# Why is the intersection of two quorums must be greater than N/3 when proving streamlet?

Tags: protocol, consensus

Why is the intersection of two quorums must be greater than N/3 when proving Streamlet, a blockchain consensus protocol [BY Chan, Elaine Shi, 2020]?

[image: The quorum] 
In Streamlet, honest node vote for proposed block in every round. When a block gain vote for more than 2N/3 distinct node, it's notarized. In this context, quorum is the set of distinct votes on a notarized block

Following statement confuses me: The quorum size have to be more than 2N/3 to ensure at most one block can be notarized in a round if the malicious node is less than N/3, because the intersection of two quorums must be greater than N/3 and only malicious block will equivocate.
This intersection greater than N/3 seems come out of nowhere or do I miss something? why can't it be smaller? like N/5 or something else?

This statement and picture are from [the material of streamlet](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/088.pdf) in principles of blockchains (ECE 598PV) from illinois and also from [the lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BL1Y-e5VOY&t=920s&ab_channel=indcca) (14:47) given by the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of the inclusion exclusion principle. Otherwise, the total number of nodes will be 2n/3+2n/3-(something <1/3) > n.